# How to get correct array Length in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why I getting **2020** array length what process I am missing Please run this code into browser and see result,please give me feedback which I am missing.

```js
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array = new Array();
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new = new Array();
var news = '[{"2018":["testeer","testeer2","testeer3"],"2019":["sd","sd2","sd3"]},{"2018":["dfg"],"2019":["praafd"]}]';
var obj = $.parseJSON(news);
var i = 0;
$.each(obj, function (i, objectData) {
  i++;
  if(i == 1) {
    $.each(objectData, function (key, obj_new) {
      if(key == '2018') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
      } 
      if(key == '2019') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
      }
    });
  } 
  else if(i == 2) {
    $.each(objectData, function (key, obj_new) {
      if(key == '2018') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new);     
      } 
      if(key == '2019') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new);
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array.length, offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what should be your final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays make sense for ordered lists of data (which should not have blank spots, such as with sparse arrays). Your `offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array` is a *spare* array - you're assigning to an index when `[index - 1]` does not exist in the array - which results in a very odd structure - 2017 `<empty>` elements followed by two *actual* elements. You might consider using an *object* instead of an array:

```
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array = {};
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new = {};
```

To get the "length" of the resulting object, you can check the length of its `keys`:

```
Object.keys(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array).length
```

That way, lines like

```
offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array[key] = obj_new;
```

will *only* result in associating the property name `[key]` with the value `obj_new`, *without also causing spare-array weirdness* (like the making the `.length` of the collection huge in the process).

```js
// var x = ['vdf','dsgfdsfds','dsgfdfgdsfds'];
// console.log(x);
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array = {};
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new = {};
var news = '[{"2018":["testeer","testeer2","testeer3"],"2019":["sd","sd2","sd3"]},{"2018":["dfg"],"2019":["praafd"]}]';
var obj = $.parseJSON(news);
var i = 0;
$.each(obj, function(i, objectData) {
  i++;
  if (i == 1) {
    $.each(objectData, function(key, obj_new) {
      if (key == '2018') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
      }
      if (key == '2019') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
      }
    });
  } else if (i == 2) {
    $.each(objectData, function(key, obj_new) {
      if (key == '2018') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new);                  
      }
      if (key == '2019') {
        offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new[key] = obj_new;
        //console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new);
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

would suggest to construct a new obj like `tmpObj` and push `key` & `value` and then push `tmpObj` into array. and you will get the array lenght also.

**temp object construction**

```
var tmpObj = {};
tmpObj[key] = tmpObj[key] || [];
tmpObj[key].push(obj_new);
```

try below code snippet.

```js
var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array = new Array();
  var offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new = new Array();
  
  var news = '[{"2018":["testeer","testeer2","testeer3"],"2019":["sd","sd2","sd3"]},{"2018":["dfg"],"2019":["praafd"]}]';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(news);
    var i = 0;
    $.each(obj, function (i, objectData) {
        i++;                      
        if(i == 1) {
            $.each(objectData, function (key, obj_new) {
              var tmpObj = {};
                if(key == '2018') {
                    tmpObj[key] = tmpObj[key] || [];
                    tmpObj[key].push(obj_new);
                offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array.push(tmpObj );
                }   
                if(key == '2019') {
                   tmpObj[key] = tmpObj[key] || [];
                    tmpObj[key].push(obj_new);
                    offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array.push(tmpObj);
                }
            });
        } 
        else if(i == 2) {
            $.each(objectData, function (key, obj_new) {
               var tmpObj = {};                      
                if(key == '2018') {
                  tmpObj[key] = tmpObj[key] || [];
                    tmpObj[key].push(obj_new);
                    offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new.push(tmpObj);
                }   
                if(key == '2019') {
                tmpObj[key] = tmpObj[key] || [];
                    tmpObj[key].push(obj_new);
                    offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_new.push(tmpObj);
                }
            });
        }
    });

console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array.length, '---', offline_rijksmuseum_child_barcodes_array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```